# DB Cleaner not cleaning database after each test after switching from sqlite to PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rspec, database-cleaner

This config worked fine when I was using sqlite:

```
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end
  config.before(:each) do
    controller.stub(:should_navigate_user?).and_return(false) rescue ""
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end
  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
```

When I switched to PostgreSQL I began getting errors when tests depended on the id number of entries in the database.  I looked at the database during the tests and it was never cleaning the database.

If I switch to the following config:

```
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end
  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
    controller.stub(:should_navigate_user?).and_return(false) rescue ""
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end
  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
```

All of my tests pass, but I'm having to call clean before *and* after my methods tests?

I shouldn't have to clean the database before and after each test - right?  I feel like I'm misunderstanding something somewhere.  What am I failing to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used sqlite in non-persistent mode. PostgreSQL doesn't have such options, always persistent. Use drop database/create database to clean it complettely.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using postgres with the database cleaner.  Its working well now, but I remember having trouble at first.  I pasted my config below.  You can stick this in your spec_helper.rb, or in another file such as /support/database_cleaner.rb

```
RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end

  config.before(:each, :js => true) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

end
```

Also make sure you turn the transactional fixtures off in the spec_helper:

```
config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
```

Comment: I am using the same config, and it still not cleaning for me.

Comment: Why would you downvote me for that? @WebQube?  There's not reason for it.  That is a valid config, and it works.  Perhaps you should give more information about your situation before randomly down voting.

Comment: Sorry for that, but that is what I think, BTW now stack won't let up vote.